# repeatedly calling a c++ method from cython suddenly is much slower

Tags: c++, cython

I often wrap c++ classes using cython. All the calculations are done in c++ and cython is only used to pass variables to the constructor and get the results from c++.

For a recent project, I am having the following problem: The code (which initializes a class and then calls a method) always runs fine initially, but after calling the same method repeatedly (I can't reproduce when exactly), it suddenly runs a factor of at least 1000 slower than normal when calling the same method.

My question is: What could cause such a seemingly random behavior and how would you go about debugging it?

I know this is impossible to solve without seeing the code, but it's large and I don't know where the problematic behavior comes from. I'm just asking for hints and strategies of how to solve it.

Things I've tried:

- Checked the c++ code for leaks.
- tried different compiler directives (#cython: wraparound=False, boundscheck=False, ...)

A hint could be that if I run the python code without the --pylab option of ipython it complains about a symbol not being found, but that's the only problem I have been able to identify.

Comment: Try running `top` at the same time to see if you're getting e.g. a sudden increase in page faults at the same time as the slow-down.

Comment: Yes! huge increase of faults in top. What does that mean?

Comment: It most likely means that *something* is leaking memory - try watching the memory usage for your process(es) and see if you get an idea of how many MB per iteration is being leaked - that might give you a clue as to what's not being freed.

Comment: Had a similar problem recently, in my case this was an "Out of bounds on buffer access" which I did not notice due to "boundcheck=False". Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 0):

It was an uninitialized member that occasionally caused a problem, not a memory leak. Thanks to those who tried to help!

The issue with ipython remains, but I posted that in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357027/cython-code-only-working-with-pylab-option) question.